# attachMovie() not working

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

Here's my code:

```
var people:Array = [
    {
        image: "1.jpg",
        labels: 
            [
                "Valium dependant",
                "Anger issues",
                "Single parent"
            ]
    },{
        image: "2.jpg",
        labels: 
            [
                "Alcoholic",
                "Bipolar disorder",
                "Smokes cannabis"
            ]
    },{
        image: "3.jpg",
        labels: 
            [
                "Glue sniffer",
                "Suffers from anxiety",
                "Has terminal cancer"
            ]       
    },{
        image: "4.jpg",
        labels: 
            [
                "Ecstasy user",
                "Binge drinker",
                "Depressed"
            ]       
    },{
        image: "5.jpg",
        labels: 
            [
                "Homeless",
                "Heroin user",
                "Smokes"
            ]       
    },{
        image: "6.jpg",
        labels: 
            [
                "Uses poppers",
                "LSD user",
                "Cocaine user"
            ]       
    }
];

var thumb_container:MovieClip = this.thumb_container;
for (index in people) {
    var thumb:MovieClip = thumb_container.attachMovie("Thumbnail", "thumb_" + index, thumb_container.getNextHighestDepth());
    var image_container:MovieClip = thumb.image_container;
    var image:MovieClip = image_container.attachMovie(people[index].image, "image_" + index, image_container.getNextHighestDepth());
    trace(image);
}
```

The problem is `trace(image)` returns `_level0.thumb_container.thumb_0.image_container` which is the parent of `image`. I can't work out why it isn't returning the image I attached (The image does not appear in the SWF either).

Note: The `image` property in the `people` array is the linkage id exported for ActionScript.

**Edit:** If I put them in a MovieClip and load them they work fine, but there seem to be many people using `attachMovie()` with images

Comment: Does `image` property in the array `people` holds the **linkage id** of the movieclip in the **library** or **url** for the external resource?

Comment: @Moorthy it holds the linkage id of the image in the library

Comment: Your code is working good for me(it does log the image and displays it in the image container). But there were no positions set for any of the mc, so you should make sure the `thumb` movieclip never overlaps each other.

Comment: @Moorthy I do position them separately but that is unnecessary code for here. Are you using plain bitmap assets or bitmaps contained in a MovieClip?

Comment: I have used bitmaps contained in a MovieClip.

Comment: Got the same problem when tried using plain bitmap assets

Comment: `attachMovie` is to load/attach a mc from the library not any other types. So it is not recognizing the image linkage id(because it is a bitmap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't load bitmap using `MovieClip.attachMovie` because it can't recognize the bitmap files. It's purpose is to load movieclips only and not other types. So you have to make bitmap data first then attach this bitmap data to the movieclip.

```
var thumb_container:MovieClip = this.thumb_container;
for (index in people) {
    var thumb:MovieClip = thumb_container.attachMovie("Thumbnail", "thumb_" + index, thumb_container.getNextHighestDepth());
    var image_container:MovieClip = thumb.image_container;
    var bmp:BitmapData = BitmapData.loadBitmap(people[index].image);
    var image:MovieClip = image_container.attachBitmap(bmp, image_container.getNextHighestDepth());
    trace(image);
}
```

It returns the `image` and displays it as well.

Comment: Thanks, although your `attachBitmap()` is wrong as there is no paramater to supply an instance name.

Comment: @GeorgeReith Sorry I forgot to delete that while editing ur code. I edited the code now